# Distortion on flac file

Tags: windows-11

Just switched to KMPlayer as it was recommended, FLAC file sounds distorted, in Windows 11 Pro, whereas it plays fine with built-in media player and VLC player, Does anyone know of a reason? Have I done something wrong? Playing through USB to a Topping DAC-FOSI AUDIO T20-ELAC B5.2.

Comment: That's going to be next to impossible to determine without a) the file & b) your exact gain-staging to output.

Comment: If you upload the suspect file, we can listen on KMPlayer on our computers to see if its reproducible.

Comment: Also, if you don't have an attachment to KMPlayer, use the built-in of VLC (or Klite's media player)

Comment: Do you need the video playback capability? If not, and you just want something different, you could try, say, foobar2000.

Comment: Just to add it's only the 64bit version if that helps, just tried 32-bit version it's fine, it's any track I've discovered. Tried headphones via Bluetooth same.

Comment: Try changing the bit-rate on your hardware output, 44.1 to 48 or vice versa.